# Find the first element of different span

Tags: javascript

I'm actually creating a script for a webpage. 
I have not the possibility to modify the actual markup.

Here is the HTML Source Code :

```
<span id="spnTrNdCnt">
     <span class="fufw" fldrnm="ibx" id="spnFldrNm">IBX</span>
     <span id="spnUC">&lrm;(
          <span id="spnCV">2</span>
     )&lrm;</span>
</span>
```

I want to get the textContent for the span id equals spnCV.
The problem is that this code is present many times in the HTML Page. So each time i try to get the textContent (`document.getElementById('spnCV').textContent`) it gives me the last value of the last item.

I would like to know if there is any way to ***get the value of this first item*** (the first span which have the id spnCV) !

Thanks a lot for any kind of help.

Comment: ids are meant to be unique

Comment: IDs MUST be unique. If they are not unique, then you do not have a valid HTML document and it cannot reliably be processed by JavaScript.

Comment: You know that ids should be unique throughout a page exactly to prevent such problems? If you need multiple occurrences use classes or `data-` attributes.

Comment: I know the document is not valid, but i just want to know if there is a possibility to retrieve the first one as i mentionned before.

Comment: This should give you all of them: `document.querySelectorAll("span[id=spnCV]");` or use `querySelector(...)` to just get the first.

Comment: Sorry if I may be off topic but why not to use jQuery? Whit this simple code yoou will get the first: 
$('#spnCV').text();
I think it's exactly what the last comment wrote in javascript

Comment: @SimonaAdriani Importing the jQuery library simply to solve this problem is unnecessary and expensive. If he has no other use for jQuery in his project, than I see no reason to import jQuery do something that is easily solvable in native Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YKNZx/)

```
  var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
     for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
     {
        if(ele[i].id=='spnCV')
        {
            // when i=0 it will be the first node
           // do something
           var text = (ele[i].innerText || ele[i].textContent);
           alert(text);
        }
     }
```

Comment: I beat you to this solution, and I provided an adequate explanation, yet, you get upvotes and I don't. Seems fair

Comment: I actually decided to delete my answer, and you should delete or modify yours too. We both failed to read the author's question fully. He wants to select only the first item. You are looping through all items. In the very least, you should break from the loop on the first occurence of `ele[i].id == 'spnCV'`.

Comment: thats why i mentioned, when i will be 0 it will be the first item

Comment: So break from the loop there.

Comment: the person who asked will have to use some brain to manipulate that accordingly

Comment: If the author has to manipulate your "answer" in order to make it an appropriate answer, then it is not an "answer" at all.

Comment: We are here to help them, not to do home work. Thats simple loop break  can be supposed to add by user. :-)

Comment: Or you could take .5s to make your answer accurately address the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`querySelectorAll` should in theory work for CSS selectors, which don't care about the restriction regarding unique ids.

```
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('#spnCV');
var length = spans.length;

for (var i=0; i<length; i++) {
  console.log('Span ' + i, spans[i].textContent);
}
```

Working JsBin: http://jsbin.com/oriSiNa/1/edit

**EDIT:**

Since you only need the first span, then it's even easier:

```
var value = document.querySelector('#spnCV').textContent;
```

Comment: This is the best answer, provided the author only needs to support IE8+.

Answer (score 0):

ID's must be unique as is mentioned before, but since you cannot change the source, please check out [firstchild](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_element_firstchild.asp), assuming that you can add some js somehow.